# How to Get UTC DateTime

Tags: java, android, calendar

How can I get UTC DateTime from the following code? Right now with these lines of code, I get an output like this `Fri Dec 31 05:30:00 IST 9999`. Is this output is correct? I mean to say is this time is the UTC time. Any suggestions or help?

**Code snapshot**

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
cal.set(9999, 11, 31, 0, 0, 0); 
        
Date date = cal.getTime();
System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the output is correct in that it's what I'd expect for midnight UTC when you're running on a system in IST. `Date.toString()` *always* uses your system local time zone - because it doesn't have any other information. A `Calendar` knows its time zone, but a `Date` doesn't. The underlying information is just "the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch".

If you want to convert a `Date` to a textual representation in a particular time zone, use `SimpleDateFormat` and specify the time zone there.

Comment: Acually i am totally confused with UTC & local time. Actually my requirement is like that, I have an Date array of size 20, I need to initialized this array with the default date which i show in the above example. So earlier what i did is like this http://pastebin.com/FKhmV1bf, But they said this is not correct because in this code i am storing local time to the array. What they want is to store UTC DateTime to the array. So how that can be done.   Help me to sort this out

Comment: @AndroidDev: the code you provided in the question already uses UTC, so that's fine. It would help in the future if you could provide all the relevant context in the question.

Comment: One last question, How can i convert local DateTime to UTC, I mean to say suppose i have local time stored in my Date variable like Date localDateTime = "Tue Jul 22 16:57:00 GMT+05:30 2014". How can I convert this DateTime to UTC DateTime.

Comment: @AndroidDev: Well that's not going to even compile... but if you're trying to parse something like that, I suggest you search through other questions on Stack Overflow - it's been addressed several times.

Comment: @AndroidDev Search StackOverflow for "Joda" (yes, that spelling, 'joda') and "DateTimeZone" to learn how to handle these date-time values in a sensible manner.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you're using the Date.toString() method that returns the local time zone.

You can use this code to get the current time in UTC:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

And then just use that object to get the time you want and use it, do note that cal.getTimeInMillis() or getTime() both return the time from the Epoch that is set to January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT (Gregorian). So if you want to print the time or use it for something other then calculate the difference in time you can use, for example:

```
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

However if you want to get the difference of time between this time and another you should create another calendar instance for that other time (because of the way getTimeInMillis() work). So you can just do something like:

```
Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
time.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
time.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
time.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day_of_month);
time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour_of_day);
time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
time.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);
long difInMillis = cal.getTimeInMillis() - time.getTimeInMillis();
```

Also you should always remember that the month starts from 0 and not from 1, to be sure you can use Calendar.[your_month_here] and check the values.

You can find more information here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html